# unable to display image from FILE URI, Ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to display image taken from camera and displaying it to the view. I have searched for this answer on many websites but nothing worked. I have tried DomSanitizer, Base64 and even photo-library but the image returned from them is not displayed.

My home.ts file is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  myPhoto:any;
  image;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera: Camera, public DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  }

  takePhoto(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      targetHeight: 320,
      targetWidth: 320,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
     // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
     this.myPhoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
     this.image = imageData;
     console.log(this.myPhoto);
     alert(this.myPhoto);
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my home.html code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="takePhoto()" >Take Photo</button>

  <!-- <img src="{{myPhoto}}"/> -->
  <!-- <img src="{{image}}"/> -->
  <!-- <img [src]="DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(myPhoto)"/> -->
  <!-- <img data-ng-src="{{myPhoto}}"/> -->
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1533211220154.jpg"/>
</ion-content>
```

The commented code here is that i have tried but not succeeded.

Comment: try with this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/3.3.0/api/util/normalizeURL/

Comment: Give a try to the **MediaCapture** plugin which also works fine.

Comment: you can display your image like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934321/5697686

Answer (score 2):

I used the file plugin and its method readAsDataURL. It worked fine for me. Hope it'll helps people out there :)

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      allowEdit: true,
      sourceType:  this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA ,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      correctOrientation: true,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    }

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

    //imageData will hold the full file path so we need to extract filename and path using file plugin 
     var filename = imageData.substring(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     var path =  imageData.substring(0,imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    //then use it in the readAsDataURL method of cordova file plugin
    //this.file is declared in constructor file :File
         this.file.readAsDataURL(path, filename).then(res=>{
           item.pic = res;
         });
}, (err) => {
 alert(err);
});
```

[link for ionic cordova file plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/)

Comment: its not working when take image from gallery, only in android, in iOS its working fine, has anyone have solution for this?

Comment: readAsDataURL method converting image file url to base64 img. so why not use direct base64 string from plugin (destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URI)

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got solution :

In component :

```
takePhoto(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      targetHeight: 320,
      targetWidth: 320,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imgFileUri) => {
     this.myImg = (<any>window).Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imgFileUri);
    }, (err) => {
     console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

In html :

```
<img [src]="myImg" />
```

Note : 
[cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#migrating-to-4x) >= 4

Comment: did you try in ionic 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

From new ionic and capacitor you can do it like this:

```
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

Capacitor.convertFileSrc(filePath);
```

**[File Protocol​](https://ionicframework.com/docs/core-concepts/webview)**

Capacitor and Cordova apps are hosted on a local HTTP server and are served with the http:// protocol. Some plugins, however, attempt to access device files via the file:// protocol. To avoid difficulties between http:// and file://, paths to device files must be rewritten to use the local HTTP server. For example, file:///path/to/device/file must be rewritten as http://://path/to/device/file before being rendered in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in your ts file

```
takePhoto(){
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      targetHeight: 320,
      targetWidth: 320,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
      this.myPhoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.image = imageData;
      console.log(this.myPhoto);
    }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
    });
  }
```

Use this in your html

```
<img [src]="myPhoto"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i tried your solution by installing APK on android 8.1.0 but it was unsuccessful :(

Comment: I am getting not error, If i console this.myPhoto i get the file path, but the image i get in view is broken.

Comment: if you set `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` you should get a base64 encoded string.

Comment: i have tried to show image in view by trying:
* with and without Base64 string
* with data_url and file_url
* storage permission is checked

I am getting the path of the file, i checked it on the storage but still unable to show it in view.
Just for insight
My ionic version is 4.0.5
NPM version: 6.1.0
node -v 10.7.0
cordova -v 8.0.0

Comment: DATA_URL should be avoided as (It can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI if possible)
For FILE_URI we can convert it to read as base64 (If needed)

Answer (score -1):

Modify your **home.ts** in following way,

```
  private openGallery(): void {
    let cameraOptions = {
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      quality: 100,
      targetWidth: 1000,
      targetHeight: 1000,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      correctOrientation: true
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
      .then(file_uri => this.imageSrc = file_uri,
      err => console.log(err));
  }
```

In your html file,

```
<img [src]="imageSrc"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i tried your solution by installing APK on android 8.1.0 but it was unsuccessful :(

Comment: It might be permission related issue. Can you please check app-permissions in settings.

Comment: Storage permission is checked.