# Not allowed to load local resource: ionic 3 android

Tags: android, file, path, ionic3, android-6.0-marshmallow

*I am using ionic 3 android build apk and trying to laod image from **file:///storage/emulated/0/data/io.ionic.vdeovalet/cache/image.jpeg***

```
    takePicture(sourceType) {
        try {
    // Create options for the Camera Dialog
          var options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            sourceType: sourceType,
          };
          this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
    // Special handling for Android library
            if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType ===
              this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
              this.filePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath)
                .then(filePath => {
                  let correctPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                  let currentName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                    imagePath.lastIndexOf('?'));
                  this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
                  this.lastImage = filePath;
                });
            } else {
              var currentName = imagePath.substr(imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
              var correctPath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
              this.copyFileToLocalDir(correctPath, currentName, this.createFileName());
            }
          }, (err) => {
            this.presentToast('Error while selecting image.');
          });


        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }


      }
```

**Error: Not allowed to load local resource**
**android 6.0.1**

Comment: Hello Muneeb, did you solved it? I have the same problem here.

Answer (score 35):

> No Need To Downgrade just write this code.

```
private win: any = window;
    this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(path);
```

Comment: ..write this code where? You should explain your code with reason.

Comment: private win: any = window;  //write it at variable declaration.and this -> "this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(path);" at where you get your path like "file:///storage/emulated/0/data/io.ionic.vdeovalet/cache/image.jpeg" or where you get an error.@Sayed

Comment: To declare win: any did the trick for me. This answer has to be marked as the correct solution.

Comment: you are so awesome.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issues and it turns out that
The new ionic webview plugin is the cause for the problem.

The new plugin: cordova-plugin-ionic-webview @ 2.x seem unstable...

to get it working downgraded back to cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1 and all should work

Steps:

**1.** uninstall webview

```
ionic cordova plugins rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

**2.** install old one:

```
ionic cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
```

**3.** clean cordova

```
cordova clean android
```

Comment: This is the same thing I ran into.  Additionally, code-push seems to break with this 2.x version of ionic-webview.  So there may be some decent reasons to stay on 1.2.1.  https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/451

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day

Comment: So many "solutions" and this was the final one to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

When Ionic is used with Capacitor, we can get the correct path of an image or other resource on a native device by:

```
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';

Capacitor.convertFileSrc(filePath);
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/core-concepts/webview

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me was `convertFileSrc()`

`let win: any = window;
 let safeURL = win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(this.file.dataDirectory+'data/yourFile.png');`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

1) https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-images/
In this tutorial, ionic 2 & ionic 3 is the best way to upload and upload images.

2) https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/ In this tutorial, ionic 4 is the best way to upload and upload images.

i also use these... and it working fine...

And I have also faced the problem of

> not allowed to load local resource

You can see here :
[@ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.13 : Not allowed to load local resource : with webview 2.2.3 - Ionic CLI 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395712/ionic-angular-4-0-0-beta-13-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-with-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 10
    , destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    , mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    // Optional , correctOrientation: true
    , sourceType: sourceType == 0 ? this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA : this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    // Optional , saveToPhotoAlbum: true
};

this.camera.getPicture(options).then(imageBase64 => {
    let txtForImage = `data:image/jpeg;base64,` + imageBase64;
    this.imageToLoad = txtForImage;
})
.catch(error => {
    alert("Error: " + error);
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this line into your index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
img-src 'self' data: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com;
script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com;" />
```

Then, write this function instead of your one, note that what this script does is returning the photo as base64

```
getImageFromCamera() {
const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 20,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    allowEdit: false
};
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
    this.imageURI = imageData;
    this.imageName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // Create a folder in memory location
    this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Demo')
        .then(() => {
            this.fileCreated = true;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("checkDir: Error");
            this.presentToast("checkDir Failed");
        });
    if (this.fileCreated) {
        this.presentToast("Directory Already exist");
    }
    else {
        this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "Demo", true)
            .then((res) => {
                this.presentToast("Directory Created");
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("Directory Creation Error:");
            });
    }

    //FILE MOVE CODE
    let tempPath = this.imageURI.substr(0, this.imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    let androidPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Bexel/';
    this.imageString = androidPath + this.imageName;

    this.file.moveFile(tempPath, this.imageName, androidPath, this.imageName)
        .then((res) => {
            this.presentToast("Image Saved Successfully");
            this.readImage(this.imageString);

        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Image Copy Failed");
            this.presentToast("Image Copy Failed");
        });
    //Complete File Move Code

    this.toDataURL(this.imageURI, function (dataUrl) {
        console.log('RESULT:' + dataUrl);
    });
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    this.presentToast(JSON.stringify(err));
  });
}
presentToast(msg) {
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: msg,
    duration: 2000
});
toast.present();
}
toDataURL(url, callback) {
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
};
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
}
readImage(filePath) {
let tempPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
let imageName = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

this.file.readAsDataURL(tempPath, imageName)
    .then((res) => {
        this.presentToast("Image Get Done");
        this.imageUrl = res;
    }, (err) => {
        this.presentToast("Image Get Error");
    });
}
```

It sees like it's an issue with content CSP (content security policy), the meta tag should fix this issue, then the code will read the photo as base64, then here you go, in HTML:

```
<img [src]="imageUrl">
```

And you can modify the function to remove unnecessary console.log, i was just testing.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was use the proper Imagepicker Options, the output type did it:

```
  const options: ImagePickerOptions = {
    maximumImagesCount: 1,
    outputType: 1,
    quality: 50
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let win: any = window; // hack ionic/angular compilator
var myURL = win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(myURL);
```