# window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc not working in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, wkwebview, content-security-policy

I am trying to display image selected from camera/gallery using `cordova-plugin-camera` plugin and used `window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc()` for **Rewriting** `file://` due to wkwebview.

It works fine in android platform but in iOS platform it gives error for Content Security Policy

For example I am getting 
`file:///Users/CN339/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXXXXX/data/Containers/Data/Application/XXXXX/Library/NoCloud/cdv_photo_002.jpg`
from camera plugin and after using `window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc` on previous local url I am getting below error.

[Content Security Policy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imTfI.png)

Comment: You can use normalize: https://ionicframework.com/docs/3.2.0/api/util/normalizeURL/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used it also but it is showing deprecated, recommends to use window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc instead. and it is not working as well

Comment: @VinayThakur Have u found the solution?

Comment: @Abdu4 Yes. You have to use window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc along with Angular's DomSanitizer bypassSecurityTrustUrl.

Comment: @VinayThakur can you please explain in detail how to use DomSanitizer bypassSecurityTrustUrl with use window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc

Comment: @VinayThakur Can you add the codes as the answer, then you can make it as the accepted answer and of course we can upvote the answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a lot of methods to load local files such images or videos. I tried using

- normalizeUrl (from ionic-angular)
- regex and replace the local file path: path.replace(/^file:///, '')
- window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc()

None of above worked for me. The only way I could load a local file was using

> window['Ionic']['WebView'].convertFileSrc(path);

Hope it works as you want. I have only tested it on Android

**UPDATE**
You can use win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(), like third bullet, only if you declare win: any = window.
To define win as any did the trick for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934321/10243902

Comment: Finally, after trying all possible ways (｡◕‿◕｡)

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem on iOS after ionic-webview suddenly stopped working, so I uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin:

cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

`window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc` started working like a charm again.

Answer (score -1):

this.tempSchemeImagePath =  window['Ionic']['WebView'].convertFileSrc(nativeURL);

Comment: please put your code inside a code block and explain your answer