# Ionic 4: Cannot display camera image to user

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am simply trying to allow a user to take a photo, store it as a data URI and then display that image.  For some reason this only displays a boken image link and I'm not sure I understand.  `selectImage()` should allow the user to either select an image or take a new one, then display the image.

My view:

```
<ion-row *ngIf="imageSrc">
  <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
    <img alt="cropped photo" height="500px" [src]="imageSrc" />
    <p>{{imageSrc}}</p>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Component:

```
selectImage() : void {
    this.photo.selectImageSheet().then(() => {
      if ( typeof(this.photo.imageSource) == 'number' ) {
        this.photo.pickImage(this.photo.imageSource).then(imageURI => {
          this.global.handleResponse(imageURI)
          this.imageSrc = imageURI
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Photo service:

```
pickImage(sourceType: number) : Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.selectImage(sourceType).then( imageURI => {
        resolve(imageURI)
      })
    })
  }

 selectImage(srcType : number = 1) : Promise<any> {

    let options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      sourceType: srcType,
      targetWidth: 600,
      targetHeight: 1200,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      correctOrientation: true,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.camera.getPicture(options)
        .then((imageURI) => {

          this.imageData = imageURI;

          resolve(this.imageData)
        })
        .catch(err => this.globals.handleResponse(JSON.stringify(err)))
    })
  }
```

The documentation seems pretty clear that the `FILE_URI` should be able to be set as the `src` so I'm really not sure what could be going wrong...

> ```
> navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
>     destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
>
> function onSuccess(imageURI) {
>     var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
>     image.src = imageURI;
> }
>
> function onFail(message) {
>     alert('Failed because: ' + message);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There's a popular method to fix this which is to convert the file like so:

```
    this.imageData = this.win.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imageURI);
```

It works on photos and videos. Here's the original response https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934321/10243902

Nonetheless, I prefer to show the image as an base64 right away. If you feel like using it just install the Base64 Plugin :

```
ionic cordova plugin add com-badrit-base64
npm install @ionic-native/base64
```

Initialize on the constructor

```
constructor(private base64: Base64 ){ }
```

and use it like so:

```
      this.base64.encodeFile(imageURI).then((base64Img) => {
          this.imageData = base64Img;
        })
```

Comment: After doing that I still have an issue.  The src is saved as "ionic://localhost/_app_file_/...".  Is that right?  Should it be data and not a URL?

Comment: The path looks correct. It should work either way, path or base64 data. Try using [DomSanitizer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-display-image-using-file-uri/84977/3) to display the image.